# Wygwam 'site page' link type not parsing when used within Low Variables variable

Tags: wygwam, low-variables, pages, wysiwyg, parse

I am using:
**EE 2.7.2**,
**Low Variables 2.4.0**,
**WYGWAM 3.2.2**

I have a WYGWAM field as a Low Variable, and within it, I am setting up some page links. When I create a link, under "Link Type" I chose "Site Page" and select the page on my site. However, when I output that variable on my homepage, the links are broken, and look like `href="{page_38}"`. For some reason the page url isn't getting parsed. This "Site Page" method works fine for links in my channel entries.

Any idea how to get around this? For now, I just switched to specifying the URL manually, rather than selecting the site page. Thanks!

Gary

Comment: If it helps, my variable is set for early parsing and to save as a file. It is included directly within my index template. I tried turning off early parsing and that doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For any variable that needs extra processing, like the Wygwam variable type, use the **tag syntax** rather than the variable syntax:

```
{exp:low_variables:single var="my_wygwam_var"}
```

Note that having early parsing on or off is irrelevant for the tag syntax, so you can leave it off.

Comment: I'm having the same issue on Low Variables 3.0.4 / Assets 3.0.0 / Wygwam 4.0.7 / EE 3.5.2. I tried both the tag syntax and the variable syntax. Happens regardless of what the wygwam file browser setting. Thoughts?

Comment: I am also having trouble with this. Using the tag syntax on **EE3 3.5.1** with **Wygwam 4.0.6** / **Structure 4.0.0**. Any solutions? My code (multi-language site) is: {exp:low_variables:single var="footer_block3_content_{segment_1}"}

Comment: If you're having trouble with the output of the Wygwam var, and you're using the above syntax, be sure to ask Wygwam's dev about it. LV just acts as a middle man, passing through the data that Wygwam handles.

Answer (score 1):

This has been fixed in Wygwam version 4.0.8!